# Power apps, IF statement on data card, IF value=No, then blank

Tags: list, powerapps-forms

Trying to do a simple IF statement in my power app, if my value of card a = No then value of card b = "". This is inputted in my Q2.a field. They are choice fields of Yes and No.

```
IF(Choices([@'test'].'Q2.')="No","")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define that it is the selected value from the dropdown.

So provided that the Q1 is in a datacard it would look like this for the default items where you want to have the text:

```
If(DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Q2", "No", "")
```

Hope it helps :)